# How can I get a list of column names and types from a resultset?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

Say I get a resultset back from the following query:

```
select * 
from sys.database_files;
```

For any given resultset, I want to be able to query the column names and types so I can then create tables to store the results.

What is a good way of performing this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * 
INTO YourTableName 
FROM sys.database_files;
```

Comment: I like any solution that makes two jobs into one.

Comment: There's no other solution of getting directly from TSQL the schema of a result set. Just 'select into' comes to mind. If you'd rather not use new tables, then you have to query the meta data (information_schema system views).

Comment: If you want to be really clean about it, use a temp table (like #YourTableName) instead of a user table.  That avoids changing pages in the user database, thereby keeping logging & differential backups smaller.  Kinda anal retentive, but hey, that's me!

Comment: Stop, Brent, you keep making sense :) I have been beating my head trying to remember how this was done, and it was pushed into a temp table, indeed.

Answer (score 9):

Way late to the party, but just thought I'd mention a metadata enhancement in SQL Server Denali that will make it much easier - not only to inspect the output of a query without running it (not quite the same behavior as [`SET FMTONLY ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx), which many apps use today), but also to build target tables dynamically (without all the parsing and case work involved with pulling metadata from [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)). Here is a quick example - notice you never have to actually run the query to figure out the shape of its resultset:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM sys.database_files';

SELECT name, system_type_name, collation_name
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0)
    ORDER BY column_ordinal;
```

There are some limitations, of course. If you have a query with multiple statements, the phrase "first_result_set" in the name should give a clue that you will only receive information about the first statement *that returns data* - it will not stop at a leading `SET NOCOUNT ON;` for example. There are also going to be issues if you are referencing > 3-part names either directly or by trying to follow a view or synonym. But for the majority of use cases this will be a welcome simplification.

I blogged a lot more details back in December, also describing some of the other metadata enhancements:

- https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-enhancements